# Slide the number value so that it is bigger than the left column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have a result table like this

```
id | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4
a  | 1  |  1 | 2  | 5
b  | 2  |  3 | 5  | 5
c  | 2  |  2 | 2  | 2
```

Is there any way that i can slide the same value columns up until there's column with same value within rows?

Expected result

```
id | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4
a  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 5
b  | 2  | 3  | 5  | 6
c  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5
```

Logic behind it (a):

1. p1 = p2 -> slide up p2 to 2 [p1 = 1, p2 = 2]
2. new p2 = p3 -> slide up p3 to 3 [p1 = 1, p2 = 2, p3 = 3]
3. finish because all value is not same within row

Comment: how p4 is being calculated?

Comment: @Fahmi it same, but on the case that i bring (id:a) is stop until adjusting p3 because all of the value is not same anymore. p1=1, p2=2, p3=3, and p4=5.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret this problem as increasing the values of the `p` columns until they are all increasing an distinct *within a row*.

I think this is an inherently iterative problem.  That suggests a brute force approach -- calculating each new `p` value separately.

Actually, this isn't that bad:

```
with t as (
      select 'a' as id, 1 as p1, 1 as p2, 2 as p3, 5 as p4 union all
      select 'b', 2, 3, 5, 5 union all
      select 'd', 2, 2, 3, 3 union all
      select 'c', 2, 2, 2, 2
     )
select t.*,
       (case when p4 <= new_p3 then new_p3 + 1 else p4 end) as new_p4
from (select t.*,
             (case when p3 <= new_p2 then new_p2 + 1 else p3 end) as new_p3
      from (select t.*, p1 as new_p1,
                   (case when p2 <= p1 then p1 + 1 else p2 end) as new_p2,
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Note that I added a new row for testing, 2/2/3/3.  This also seems to be a difficult case.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and makes use of JS UDF

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION slider(t STRUCT<p1 INT64, p2 INT64, p3 INT64, p4 INT64>)
RETURNS STRUCT<p1 INT64, p2 INT64, p3 INT64, p4 INT64>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  r = []; for (v in t) r.push(t[v]);
  prev = r[0]; for (i = 1; i < r.length; i++) {
    if(r[i] <= prev) r[i] = ++prev;
    prev = r[i];
  }
  i = 0; for (v in t) t[v] = r[i++];  
  return t;
""";
SELECT id, slider(STRUCT(p1, p2, p3, p4)).*
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION slider(t STRUCT<p1 INT64, p2 INT64, p3 INT64, p4 INT64>)
RETURNS STRUCT<p1 INT64, p2 INT64, p3 INT64, p4 INT64>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  r = []; for (v in t) r.push(t[v]);
  prev = r[0]; for (i = 1; i < r.length; i++) {
    if(r[i] <= prev) r[i] = ++prev;
    prev = r[i];
  }
  i = 0; for (v in t) t[v] = r[i++];  
  return t;
""";
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' AS id, 1 AS p1, 1 AS p2, 2 AS p3, 5 AS p4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 2, 3, 5, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', 2, 2, 2, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd', 2, 2, 3, 3 
)
SELECT id, slider(STRUCT(p1, p2, p3, p4)).*
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row id  p1  p2  p3  p4   
1   a   1   2   3   5    
2   b   2   3   5   6    
3   c   2   3   4   5    
4   d   2   3   4   5
```